# Stored procedure not returning any value after taking id of particular item

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[T_TransactionSummary]  
                        @startDate datetime,  
                        @endDate datetime,       
                        @locations nvarchar(50)      
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @fromDate datetime = CONVERT(varchar(10), @startDate, 121) + ' 00:00:00.000';
    DECLARE @toDate datetime = CONVERT(varchar(10), @endDate, 121) + ' 11:59:59.999';

    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS CarCount,
        Location_tbl.LocName,
        REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(11), Transaction_tbl.dtime, 113), ' ', '-') AS Date_time,
        CASE Transaction_tbl.Compl
            WHEN 'True' THEN 'Complementary'   
            WHEN 'False' THEN 'Non-Complementary'
            ELSE 'Other'
        END AS Expr1,
        VType_tbl.Vtype,
        CASE
            WHEN (VType_tbl.Vtype = 'Normal' AND Transaction_tbl.Compl = 'False') THEN COUNT(*) * 50
            WHEN (VType_tbl.Vtype = 'VIP' AND Transaction_tbl.Compl = 'False') THEN COUNT(*) * 100
            ELSE 0
        END AS Total,
        CASE
            WHEN Transaction_tbl.Paid = 'False' THEN 0
            ELSE SUM(Transaction_tbl.PAmount)
        END AS CIH
    FROM
        Transaction_tbl INNER JOIN
        Location_tbl ON (Transaction_tbl.Locid = Location_tbl.Locid) LEFT OUTER JOIN  
        VType_tbl ON (Transaction_tbl.vtid = VType_tbl.vtid) LEFT OUTER JOIN  
        Make_tbl ON (Transaction_tbl.mkid = Make_tbl.mkid) LEFT OUTER JOIN  
        Color_tbl ON (Transaction_tbl.Colid = Color_tbl.colid) LEFT OUTER JOIN  
        PlateSource_tbl ON (Transaction_tbl.PSID = PlateSource_tbl.PSID)  
    WHERE
        (Transaction_tbl.dtime BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate)   
    AND (Location_tbl.Locid IN (SELECT locid FROM location_tbl WHERE locname IN (@locations)))  
    GROUP BY
        Location_tbl.LocName,
        REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(11), Transaction_tbl.dtime, 113), ' ', '-'),
        VType_tbl.Vtype, Transaction_tbl.Compl, Transaction_tbl.Paid  
    ORDER BY
        Location_tbl.LocName,
        Date_time DESC,
        VType_tbl.Vtype,
        Transaction_tbl.Compl  
END
```

I am passing Date and locations like this:

```
@startDate = '2013-01-01',
@endDate = '2013-10-01',
@locations = 'Blooming Dale,Fashion Avenue'
```

but am not getting any value...what is wrong with my stored procedure

Comment: This is really difficlut to read!!!

Comment: Just a tip in general: if you make sure that the question you ask is formatted so that it's easy to read, and you provide relevant information (like db structure) and some sample data chances are much bigger that someone will invest his or hers time to try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you are passing comma separated values in @locations parameters and expecting that SQL server will handle it .. SQL server will not handle this automatically either you need to change your condition to **Charindex(','''+cast(locname as varchar)+''',', @locations) > 0(which i have done in following logic)** or you need to write a dynamic query.

can you try following stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[T_TransactionSummary]  
                        @startDate datetime,  
                        @endDate datetime,       
                        @locations nvarchar(50)      
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @fromDate datetime = CONVERT(varchar(10), @startDate, 121) + ' 00:00:00.000';
    DECLARE @toDate datetime = CONVERT(varchar(10), @endDate, 121) + ' 11:59:59.999';

    SELECT
        COUNT(*) AS CarCount,
        Location_tbl.LocName,
        REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(11), Transaction_tbl.dtime, 113), ' ', '-') AS Date_time,
        CASE Transaction_tbl.Compl
            WHEN 'True' THEN 'Complementary'   
            WHEN 'False' THEN 'Non-Complementary'
            ELSE 'Other'
        END AS Expr1,
        VType_tbl.Vtype,
        CASE
            WHEN (VType_tbl.Vtype = 'Normal' AND Transaction_tbl.Compl = 'False') THEN COUNT(*) * 50
            WHEN (VType_tbl.Vtype = 'VIP' AND Transaction_tbl.Compl = 'False') THEN COUNT(*) * 100
            ELSE 0
        END AS Total,
        CASE
            WHEN Transaction_tbl.Paid = 'False' THEN 0
            ELSE SUM(Transaction_tbl.PAmount)
        END AS CIH
    FROM
        Transaction_tbl INNER JOIN
        Location_tbl ON (Transaction_tbl.Locid = Location_tbl.Locid) LEFT OUTER JOIN  
        VType_tbl ON (Transaction_tbl.vtid = VType_tbl.vtid) LEFT OUTER JOIN  
        Make_tbl ON (Transaction_tbl.mkid = Make_tbl.mkid) LEFT OUTER JOIN  
        Color_tbl ON (Transaction_tbl.Colid = Color_tbl.colid) LEFT OUTER JOIN  
        PlateSource_tbl ON (Transaction_tbl.PSID = PlateSource_tbl.PSID)  
    WHERE
        (Transaction_tbl.dtime BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate)   
    AND (Location_tbl.Locid IN (SELECT locid FROM location_tbl WHERE Charindex(','''+cast(locname as varchar)+''',', @locations) > 0))  
    GROUP BY
        Location_tbl.LocName,
        REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(11), Transaction_tbl.dtime, 113), ' ', '-'),
        VType_tbl.Vtype, Transaction_tbl.Compl, Transaction_tbl.Paid  
    ORDER BY
        Location_tbl.LocName,
        Date_time DESC,
        VType_tbl.Vtype,
        Transaction_tbl.Compl  
END
```

Comment: i know my error in this Line: AND (Location_tbl.Locid IN (SELECT locid FROM location_tbl WHERE locname IN (@locations)))

Comment: @user2878851 Dhaval is correct -- there is a problem with the '@locations' -- and you are correct as well -- there is a problem in that line that contains the "IN".  The code shown in your question would take your locations values, and put them in between the parentheses after the "IN"... BUT WITHOUT SINGLE QUOTES AROUND EACH VALUE, like the "IN" list requires.  Dhaval's code is intended to *solve* that, by replacing the "IN" altogether... though I wonder if the CHARINDEX could simply be 'Charindex(locname, @locations)'